# How to quote an expression that contains a comma in R?

Tags: r, expression, dplyr, quote

```
quote(~ source == "abc", ~ name == xyz)
```

I want to quote this expressions. I am getting following error:

```
enter Error in quote(~abc, bca) :
2 arguments passed to 'quote' which requires 1
```

Comment: Do you want a list of expressions? Because a valid expression in R can't have a comma in the middle. Commas generally only separate parameter/argument values. What are you trying to do here? If you are trying to insert two parameters to a function call, this isn't going to work.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to capture the expressions as arguments to create a new call try, `eval(substitute(alist(~abc,bca)))`. This uses the `alist()` function and captures all the arguments (credit to Hadley Wickham's Advanced R)

Or `c(quote(~source == 'abc'), quote(~name == xyz))`